# SpriteKit: How do I remove objects once they leave the screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a rock sprite that it is falling and every time it goes out of the screen I want to reset it back to the top and have it fall again. It should be a continuous cycle. Here's my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

func addRock(){
    var rock = self.childNode(withName: "rock")
    rock?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    //self.addChild(rock!)
}

override func sceneDidLoad() {
    //bRock = self.childNode(withName: "rock")
    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //addRock()
    var rock = self.childNode(withName: "rock")
    rock?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    /*if (Int((rock?.position.y)!) < Int((self.view?.scene?.view?.bounds.minY)!)){
        print("out of screen")
        rock?.removeFromParent()
        addRock()
    }*/
    }


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    var rock = self.childNode(withName: "rock")
    //rock?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    if (!intersects(rock!)){
     print("out of screen")
     rock?.removeFromParent()
     addRock()
     }

}
}
```

I have the rock coming on the screen and then falling. Once it leaves the screen, it does not reset and I get an error. I tried placing the reset code in both the touchesBegan and update functions but neither work. If someone could guide me to the correct path, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the variable you declared is a local variable, it would be renew everytime you call the function

Comment: To add to what @WeiJay said: if you are CERTAIN that there will never be more than one rock in your view, consider making it a property of your scene, and reusing the same rock every time its position resets. Otherwise, keep using a local variable, so that the object is dealloced, and work on the coding pattern you are using,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're removing the rock node from the scene but the `addRock` method doesn't actually add a new rock, it just finds the existing node if there is one and sets a property on its `physicsBody`. Instead of removing the node, you should just change its position.

Assuming your scene has the default anchor point of (0,0), you can reset the position like this:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    if let rock = self.childNode(withName: "rock") {
    if !intersects(rock!) {
        print("out of screen")
        rock.position.y = size.height/2 // divided by 2 as discussed in comments
    }
}
```

That will reset the rock's position to the top of the scene and it should resume falling from there.

Comment: Dave - isn't the current anchor point (0.5, 0.5), so to put the *middle* of the rock at the top of the screen you'd have to do rock.position.y = size.height/2 and to put the rock just off the top of the screen you'd have to do rock.position.y = size.height/2 + rock.size.height/s

Comment: Yeah, your calculation makes sense for the anchor point (0.5,0.5). And adding half the rock's height is a good idea too. I read that the default anchor point is (0,0), but I don't have a lot of personal experience with SpriteKit.

Comment: I think that scenes created in iOS 9/Xcode 7 had an anchor point of (0, 0) and those created in iOS 10/Xcode 8 (0.5, 0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. the same rock is newly located at the right place after leaving the screen, so you just need to set the position of it in (misnamed)  `addRock` (`resetRock` should be better): `rock.position = CGPoint(...)`. But beware that you also need to reset its velocity, etc, as it was previously moved by physical laws...
2. create a new rock each time one leaves the screen in `addRock`: `let rock = SKSpriteNode(...)...` (and all the initializing code for it. Much simpler as all its physical parameters will be initialized with right values by default.
3. create a clone of an initial rock. I suppose you have a model of it in your sks file, then don't name it rock but something like (rockModel), and just clone it in `addRock` with giving it the right name `rock`. Don't forget to remove the model from the scene at the beginning. This is the usual way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about using a series of move actions in a sequence to control the rock's behaviour.  Given the move actions are already defined, in your defined sequence, pass in sequence[(falling, hide, backtotop, unhide)] - Repeat Forever.

As long as the rocks don't actually interact with anything and are just for the backdrop/background, hiding and unhiding them is a good way to give the affect they are falling.